# Change button color using keyboard shortcut C# WPF

Tags: wpf, colors, controls, inputbinding

I'm getting into some C# WPF, and am creating a simple word processor to convert normal text into wiki markup. I am new to WPF and am having trouble with something seemingly minuscule, and hopefully an easy fix.

I have a **Bold** button on my main form. When pressed it does what I need it to do, which is turn the selected text to **bold** and vice versa when pressed again. The **Bold** button also changes a pretty light blue color when pressed, then back to gray when pressed again. So sweet that works...

```
//Make Bold MAIN method
    static bool isBold = false;
    public static void boldText()
    {
        if (isBold == false)
        {

            TextSelection ts = MainWindow.thisForm.rtbMain.Selection;
           MainWindow.thisForm.btnBold.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
            if (!ts.IsEmpty)
            {

                ts.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
            }
            isBold = !isBold;

        }
        else
        {

            MainWindow.thisForm.btnBold.Background = Brushes.LightGray;
            TextSelection ts = MainWindow.thisForm.rtbMain.Selection;
            ts.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal);
            isBold = !isBold;

        }

    }
```

My issue now is for some reason when I call the code above using an **InputBinding** the selected text turns bold but the button color doesn't change... whaaaaA? I have created a custom **Command**, **Execute** and **CanExecute** Commands below:

```
  public class ToolBar
   {
     //Custom Command
           public static RoutedCommand boldShortCut = new RoutedCommand();

        //For use with Keybindings for BOLD command
            static bool canExecute = true;
            public static void myCommandExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                boldText();
                canExecute = !canExecute;
            }
            public static void myCommandCanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                e.CanExecute = true;
            }
```

I then create the **KeyGesture** and **InputBindings** in the main form's constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            thisForm = this;
            initializeFeatures();

            KeyGesture kg = new KeyGesture(Key.B, ModifierKeys.Control);
            InputBinding ib = new InputBinding(ToolBar.boldShortCut, kg);
            this.InputBindings.Add(ib);
        }
```

So this all works but for some reason the **Bold** button isn't changing color when I use the key gesture (**CTRL+B**). Is there something I need to do in XAML? Any help would be greatly appreciated and please let me know if anything is unclear or additional info is needed. Thanks guys!

Comment: Just a suggestion... instead of repeating code, put `isBold = !isBold;` outside the `if else` statements and remove one of them. Also, *for some reason the Bold button isn't changing color when I use the key gesture*... that's because your `boldText` method has no relation to the `Button`.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the tip Sheridan

Comment: You could always add a `PreviewKeyDown` handler to the `Button` and set the `Background` property to `Blue` in it if `Ctrl` and `B` is pressed and a `PreviewKeyUp` handler to set it back to normal afterwards.

Comment: Oh crikey didn't realize the second half of your first comment Sheridan, also thanks for the suggestion of using the **PreviewKeyDown** handler, I will take a look at that as well. WHen you say the `boldText()` method has no relation to the button, how would I fix that? I mean it has this: `MainWindow.thisForm.btnBold.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;`

Comment: OK i've been fighting with this for a few hours now. Is there anyway you might be able to give me an example as to how I would either give a relation to the button in the `boldText()` method, or use the **PreviewKeyDown** handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are creating (`boldShortCut`) is never being setup to do anything. A `RoutedCommand` only fires an event when it is activated. There needs to be a command binding somewhere up the tree that listens for the event and performs some logic.

Take a look at this page for an explanation of how routed commands work:
[How to: Create a RoutedCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752070.aspx)

Additionally, the only reason the text turns bold when you press Ctrl+B is because that is a built-in feature of a `RichTextBox`. In fact, `RichTextBox` has a whole lot of features that you can hook toolbar buttons up to very easily. You could save yourself a lot of time by learning how to use a `RichTextBox` before trying to reimplement its existing features.

Here is a good page to get you started: [RichTextBox Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970779.aspx)

(For a full list of existing commands that you can hook things up to, see the [EditingCommands Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.editingcommands.aspx) documentation.)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Xavier you were totally correct, I hadn't added my `Command` to `CommandBindings` in my constructor.

See the corrected code below which invokes the `boldShortcut` command in the Constructor:

```
//Constructor
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        thisForm = this;
        initializeFeatures();

        ToolBar.boldShortCut.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.M, ModifierKeys.Control));
        CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ToolBar.boldShortCut, ToolBar.myCommand, ToolBar.myCommandCanExecute));

    }
```